# How can I make a 2d gpu polygon draggable?

Tags: python, gpu

How to make the 2d gpu polygon draggable?

taken from [How can I make a 2d gpu polygon and text follow the cursor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187969/how-can-i-make-a-2d-gpu-polygon-and-text-follow-the-cursor)

```
import bpy
import bgl
import blf
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    x, y = (100, 100)
    vertices = (
        (x, y-50), (x+100, y-50),
        (x, y), (x+100, y))

    indices = (
        (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices)
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glLineWidth(1) # Set the line width
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.5))
    batch.draw(shader)

    font_id = 0  # XXX, need to find out how best to get this.

    # draw some text
    font_offset = 10
    blf.position(font_id, x+font_offset, y-font_offset*2, 0)
    blf.color(font_id, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    blf.size(font_id, 11, 72)
    blf.draw(font_id, 'Hello World')

    # restore opengl defaults
    bgl.glLineWidth(1)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)


class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal View3D Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None 

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
import bpy
# import bgl
# import blf
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from blf import color as blf_color
from blf import size as blf_size
from blf import draw as blf_draw
from blf import position as blf_position
from bgl import glEnable, GL_BLEND

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
shader_bind = shader.bind
uniform_float = shader.uniform_float
Box_indices = ((0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3))

class Box:
    __slots__ = 'L', 'R', 'B', 'T', 'batch', 'color'
    def __init__(self, L, R, B, T, color):
        self.L = L
        self.R = R
        self.B = B
        self.T = T
        self.color = color
    def update(self):
        self.batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": (
            (self.L, self.B), (self.L, self.T),
            (self.R, self.T), (self.R, self.B))}, indices=Box_indices
        )
    def draw(self):
        shader_bind()
        uniform_float("color", self.color)
        self.batch.draw(shader)

    def inbox(self, event):
        x = event.mouse_region_x
        y = event.mouse_region_y
        return self.L <= x <= self.R and self.B <= y <= self.T

    def get_height(self):
        return self.T - self.B
    def get_width(self):
        return self.R - self.L

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.L += dx
        self.R += dx
        self.B += dy
        self.T += dy
        self.update()

class Blf:
    __slots__ = 'x', 'y', 'size', 'color', 'text'
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, color, text):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.text = text
    def draw(self):
        blf_color(0, *self.color)
        blf_size(0, self.size, 72)
        blf_position(0, self.x, self.y, 0)
        blf_draw(0, self.text)
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Test Operator"

    instance = None
    handle = None
    AREA = None

    @classmethod
    def DRAW(cls):
        if cls.instance is None:
            # open new file without close the operator
            print("you need debug here, tips: bpy.app.handlers")
            return

        if bpy.context.area != cls.AREA: return # draw in one viewport only

        ins = cls.instance
        boxes = ins.boxes
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)

        boxes["rim"].draw()
        boxes["main"].draw()
        boxes["title"].draw()
        boxes["close_button"].draw()
        for b in ins.blfs.values():
            b.draw()

    def fin(self):
        print("  fin")
        cls = self.__class__
        cls.AREA.spaces[0].__class__.draw_handler_remove(cls.handle, 'WINDOW')
        self.RETURN = {'CANCELLED'}
        cls = self.__class__
        cls.handle = None
        cls.instance = None
        cls.AREA = None
        try:
            bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()
        except:
            pass

    def modal(self, context, event):
        self.sub_modal(event)
        return self.RETURN

    def modal_inside(self, event):
        boxes = self.boxes
        if boxes["main"].inbox(event) is False:
            self.RETURN = {'PASS_THROUGH'}
            self.sub_modal = self.modal_outside
            return

        if event.type == 'ESC' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            self.fin()
            return

        if boxes["title"].inbox(event):
            if boxes["close_button"].inbox(event):
                if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE' and event.value == 'PRESS':
                    self.fin()
                return

            if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE' and event.value == 'PRESS':
                self.sub_modal = self.modal_move
                self.mou_x = event.mouse_region_x
                self.mou_y = event.mouse_region_y
            return

    def modal_outside(self, event):
        if self.boxes["main"].inbox(event):
            self.RETURN = {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
            self.sub_modal = self.modal_inside
            self.modal_inside(event)
            return
    def modal_move(self, event):
        bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()
        if event.value == 'RELEASE':
            self.sub_modal = self.modal_inside
            b = self.boxes["main"]
            dx = 0
            dy = 0
            if b.L < 0: dx = - b.L
            elif b.R > bpy.context.region.width: dx = bpy.context.region.width - b.R
            if b.T > bpy.context.region.height: dy = bpy.context.region.height - b.T
            elif b.B < 0: dy = - b.B

            for b in self.boxes.values():
                b.move(dx, dy)
            for b in self.blfs.values():
                b.move(dx, dy)
            return

        dx = event.mouse_region_x - self.mou_x
        dy = event.mouse_region_y - self.mou_y
        for b in self.boxes.values():
            b.move(dx, dy)
        for b in self.blfs.values():
            b.move(dx, dy)

        self.mou_x = event.mouse_region_x
        self.mou_y = event.mouse_region_y

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # if context.area.type != 'VIEW_3D':  return {'CANCELLED'}

        cls = self.__class__
        if cls.handle is not None:  return {'CANCELLED'}

        cls.AREA = bpy.context.area
        cls.handle = cls.AREA.spaces[0].__class__.draw_handler_add(cls.DRAW, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        cls.instance = self
        self.sub_modal = self.modal_inside
        self.RETURN = {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        boxes = {}
        blfs = {}
        self.boxes = boxes
        self.blfs = blfs
        x = event.mouse_region_x
        y = event.mouse_region_y

        left = x - 200
        right = x + 200
        bottom = y - 100
        top = y + 100
        color = (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
        boxes["main"] = Box(left, right, bottom, top, color)
        boxes["rim"] = Box(left - 1, right + 1, bottom - 1, top + 1, (0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0))
        boxes["title"] = Box(left, right, top - 35, top, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
        R = right - 2
        T = top - 2
        B = boxes["title"].B + 2
        L = R - boxes["title"].get_height() + 4
        boxes["close_button"] = Box(L, R, B, T, (0.65, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
        blfs["title"] = Blf(left + 10, top - 26, 22, (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0), "Dialog")
        blfs["body"] = Blf(left + 20, top - 80, 40, (0.5, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0), "Hello")
        blfs["close_button"] = Blf(L + 6, B + 3, 33, (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0), "✕")

        for b in boxes.values():
            b.update()
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

##### Limitations

Failed when switch workspace/new file if operator is running.

Comment: How to make it draw in the context (e.g. if the context is 3d viewport then draw in SpaceView3D and if the context is node editor then draw in SpaceNodeEditor etc..)

Comment: `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(cls.DRAW, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')` change to `bpy.types.SpaceNodeEditor.draw_handler_add(cls.DRAW, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')`

Comment: All spaces you need: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Space.html#bpy.types.Space

Comment: I want to change the drawing area according to the context, If I am in Node Editor then it should draw in that area and if I am in UV Editor then it should draw in that area

Comment: I changed lines 100, 173, 179 so that it can work in other spaces, but it can't midway change the space.

Comment: Can you answer this question please? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271859/how-to-make-it-draggable-and-clickable-from-multiple-region-window-area