# How to make it draggable and clickable from multiple region/window/area?

Tags: python, gpu

I want to make it draggable and clickable from multiple viewport areas.

I tried but it works only in the area where the operator is called from and when I join the second area to the original area then the color doesn't change

OR

Make it similar to `Text Info` and `Statistics`
which can toggle based on viewport area

[image]

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
import bgl
import bmesh
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from bpy.types import Operator
from mathutils import Matrix


class XX_OT_test(Operator):
    bl_idname = "xx.test"
    bl_label = "Test"
    
    def shader(self, vertices, indices, type, color):
        bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
        bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
        if type == 'LINES':
            bgl.glLineWidth(1)
            bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH)

        shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, type, {'pos': vertices}, indices=indices)

        shader.bind()
        shader.uniform_float('color', color)
        batch.draw(shader)

    def draw_callback_px(self, event):
        vertices = (
            (100, 100), (300, 100),
            (100, 200), (300, 200))

        indices = (
            (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

        self.shader(vertices, indices, type='TRIS', color=self.color)

    def redraw_regions(self):
        for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        region.tag_redraw()

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw_callback_px, (event, ), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.window.cursor_modal_set('DEFAULT')

        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handler, 'WINDOW')
            context.window.cursor_modal_set('DEFAULT')
            self.redraw_regions()
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        self.color = (0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
        if event.mouse_region_x > 100 and event.mouse_region_x < 300 and event.mouse_region_y > 100 and event.mouse_region_y < 200:
            self.color = (0.5, 0.5, 0, 1.0)
            context.window.cursor_modal_set('SCROLL_XY')
            self.redraw_regions()

        self.redraw_regions()

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}


classes = (XX_OT_test,)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: The color doesn't change on second region because the event of the operator is always the first region event. It is not judged to be inside the rectangle. It seems impossible to change the event when you focus on other region via API. But you can hide the rectangle on other regions.  
Another solution is re-call the operator when you focus on second viewport, but I can't figure out how to auto re-call the operator when focus the second viewport.

Comment: So, I asked a question to find out how to get the correct region position for the second region: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271936/how-to-call-operator-in-other-region-from-a-modal   
If this problem can be solved, then your problem can be solved.